# Creating lambda function with conditions on one df to use in df.apply of another df

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Consider `df`

```
Index   A         B      C
0      20161001   0      24.5
1      20161001   3      26.5
2      20161001   6      21.5
3      20161001   9      29.5
4      20161001   12     20.5
5      20161002   0      30.5
6      20161002   3      22.5
7      20161002   6      25.5
...
```

Also consider `df2`

```
Index Threshold
0     25
1     27
2     29
3     30
4     25
5     30
..
```

I want to add a column `"Number of Rows"` to `df2` which contains the number of rows in `df` where `(C > Threshold) & (A >= 20161001) & (A <= 20161002)` holds true. This is basically to imply that there are conditions on more than one column in `df`

```
Index Threshold  Number of Rows 
0     25         4
1     27         2
2     29         2
3     30         1
4     25         4
5     30         1
..
```

For `Threshold=25` in `df2`, there are 4 rows in `df` where `"C"` value crosses 25.

I tried something like:

```
def foo(threshold,start,end):
    return len(df[(df['C'] > threshold) & (df['A'] > start) & (df['A'] < end)])

df2['Number of rows'] = df.apply(lambda df2: foo(df2['Threshold'],start = 20161001, end = 20161002),axis=1)
```

But this is populating the `Number of Rows` column with 0. Why is this?

Comment: Sorry, took you in the wrong direction...

Comment: My code actually works. There was a typo while I was running the code. I will leave the question here as another user has given a new way to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of Boolean Indexing and the `sum()` aggregate function

```
# Create the first dataframe (df)
df = pd.DataFrame([[20161001,0 ,24.5],
                   [20161001,3 ,26.5],
                   [20161001,6 ,21.5],
                   [20161001,9 ,29.5],
                   [20161001,12,20.5],
                   [20161002,0 ,30.5],
                   [20161002,3 ,22.5],
                   [20161002,6 ,25.5]],columns=['A','B','C'])

# Create the second dataframe (df2)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[25,27,29,30,25,30],columns=['Threshold'])

start = 20161001
end = 20161002

df2['Number of Rows'] = df2['Threshold'].apply(lambda x : ((df.C > x) & (df.A >= start) & (df.A <= end)).sum())

print(df2['Number of Rows'])

Out[]: 
       0    4
       1    2
       2    2
       3    1
       4    4
       5    1
       Name: Number of Rows, dtype: int64
```